# PHP equivalent of a Ruby assignment idiom

Tags: php, ruby

what's the PHP equivalent of Ruby's "||=" assignment idiom?

The scenario is I want to instantiate an object or array "on demand," and not necessarily when a class is initialized.

I've tried to find this in the PHP docs, but I'm having difficulty finding things I need in there (miss the Ruby).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think PHP has a similar assignment syntax. You'll have to fake it with something like this:

```
if (empty($someVar))  $someVar = "DefaultVal";
```

Note: I'm not familiar with Ruby, so I read up on the ||= operator [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators). I'm not sure how that operator, as explained at that link, would help you do what you want either, but whatever.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
<?php $someVar ?: 'default value'; ?>
```

This works well with PHP 5.3.

Comment: This works great. But only on >5.3

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right but if the value does not exist it will raise an E_NOTICE. For example for `$_GET['key']`. If `key` is not in the array of `$_GET` it will raise an E_NOTICE.

If you are working with PHP 7 (which I totally recommend to use) there's a new feature called [Null Coalesce Operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary).

This way it returns the result of its first operand if it exists and is not NULL, or else its second operand:

```
<?php $foo = $foo ?? 'default value'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those things I miss from Ruby. You can also do:

```
$foo = empty($foo) ? "default" : $foo;
```

Ugly as hell though.